# Lua: Check if a table can be looped through via ipairs & ipairs starting at 0

Tags: parsing, lua, integer, lua-table

I have a nice little Lua table parser which prints out pretty looking lua code and I love it...it works beautifully. There is a slight snag...if I go to print a table or array that has any integer keys it loops through it using `pairs` (which doesn't mess the code up ironically), but I would rather it use `ipairs` if possible. So I want to know is it possible to check a table (without physically looking at it) if it can use ipairs to loop through it first else use pairs. Then is there a way to start looping at 0 instead of Lua's default 1?

Lua Table Parser (Base code found on google, changed it to make it print more array friendly)...

```
function TableParser(name, object, tabs)
    local function serializeKeyForTable(k)
        if type(k)=="number" then
            return ""
        end
        if string.find(k,"[^A-z_-]") then
            return k
        end
        return k
    end
    local function serializeKey(k)
        if type(k)=="number" then
            if k == 0 then
                return "\t[" .. k .."] = "
            else
                return "\t"
            end
        end
        if string.find(k,"[^A-z_-]") then
            return "\t" .. k .. " = "
        end
        return "\t" .. k .. " = "
    end
    if not tabs then tabs = "" end
    local function serialize(name, object, tabs) -- = {
        local output = tabs .. (name ~= "" and name .. " = " or "") .. "{" .. "\n"
        for k,v in pairs(object) do
            if type(v) == "number" then
                output = output .. tabs .. serializeKey(k) .. v
            elseif type(v) == "string" then
                output = output .. tabs .. serializeKey(k) .. string.format("%q",v)
            elseif type(v) == "table" then
                output = output .. serialize(serializeKeyForTable(k), v, tabs.."\t")
            elseif type(v) == "boolean" then
                output = output .. tabs .. serializeKey(k) .. tostring(v)
            else
                output = output .. tabs .. serializeKey(k) .. "\"" .. tostring(v) .. "\""
            end                     
            if next(object,k) then
                output = output .. ",\n"
            end
        end
        return output .. "\n" .. tabs .. "}"
    end
    return serialize(name, object, tabs)
end
```

Comment: It's not a "parser". It's the opposite: it's a serializer (or, more correctly, a "pretty printer", b/c it cares about aesthetics).

Comment: `if string.find(k, ..` seems completely pointless. You're returning the same result in both cases regardless of the conditional outcome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> So I want to know is it possible to check a table (without physically looking at it) if it can use ipairs to loop through it first else use pairs.

Don't check, just do! Use `ipairs` first and keep track of the largest key that the `ipairs` iterator returned. Then use `pairs` to iterate again and ignore all integer keys between `1` and that largest key from `ipairs`.

If you really want to *check* whether `ipairs` will do something, then look at index `1` in the table (`rawget( object, 1 ) ~= nil`). Checking whether `ipairs` will cover *all* elements in the table is not possible without iterating the table.

> Then is there a way to start looping at 0 instead of Lua's default 1?

`ipairs(t)` returns three values: an iterator function, the table `t` as the state variable, and an initial index value `0`. If you use `-1` as initial index value, `ipairs` will start the iteration at `0` (the iterator function always increments by one before using the index value):

```
t = { 1, 2, 3, [ 0 ] = 0 }
for i,v in ipairs( t ), t, -1 do  -- only use first value returned by ipairs
  print( i, v )
end
```

However, be aware that Lua 5.2 has added support for a new metamethod `__ipairs` which allows you to return a custom iterator triplet to use for `ipairs` iteration, and the iterator function returned in this case might need different state and initial index values.

**Edit:**
To incorporate the suggestions into your code insert before the `for k,v in pairs(object) do`-loop:

```
local largest = 0
for k,v in ipairs(object) do
    largest = k
    local t = type(v)
    if t == "table" then
        output = output .. tabs .. "\t" .. serialize( "", v, tabs.."\t" )
    elseif t == "string" then
        output = output .. tabs .. "\t" .. string.format("%q", v)
    else
        output = output .. tabs .. "\t" .. tostring(v)
    end
    output = output .. ",\n"
end
```

and inside the loop add an additional `if` statement to check for array keys:

```
for k,v in pairs(object) do
   if type(k) ~= "number" or k < 1 or k > largest or math.floor(k) ~= k then
       -- if type(v) == "number" then
       -- ...
   end
end
```

If you apply this modified `TableParser` function to the following table:

```
local t = {
  1, 2, 3,
  value = "x",
  tab = {
    "a", "b", field = "y"
  }
}
print( TableParser( "", t ) )
```

the output is:

```
{
    1,
    2,
    3,
    tab = {
        "a",
        "b",
        field = "y"
    },
    value = "x"
}
```

But doing table serialization properly is tricky. E.g. your implementation doesn't handle cycles or tables as keys. See the [Lua Wiki](http://lua-users.org/wiki/TableSerialization) for some implementations.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but no matter how I do it now, I either get double the results or a bunch of blank tables when there should be data in them....ideas? Can you show me some examples including nested tables?

Comment: Good implementation, only snag is any key [0] prints at the end, but might overlook that. If I may ask, what are cycles? Also, why/how would you have a table as a key?

Comment: @B1313: If you change `ipairs(object)` to `ipairs(object),object,-1` and `k < 1` to `k < 0`, the value at index `0` will be printed with the array part. Regarding cycles: `t = {}; t[1] = t`. A table can (directly or indirectly) contain a reference to itself, or two table entries can reference the same table. Regarding tables as keys: Lookup tables/caches, for example. The point is: Lua allows it, so chances are that at some point you will come across such a case, and you'd better be prepared to handle it.

Answer (score 5):

You can always iterate a table both with `pairs` and `ipairs`, whether it makes sense or not.

- `ipairs` iterates over the sequence present in the array (which means sequential integer keys starting with 1, up to the first missing value), unless overridden with metamethod `__ipairs` (5.2).
- `pairs` iterates over all key-value pairs with `next` (thus in an unspecified order), unless overridden with metamethod `__pairs` (5.2).

Which means that `ipairs` will generally not enumerate any key-value-pair `pairs` won't show.

And there is no way to verify whether `ipairs` will enumerate all keys `pairs` will enumerate, but enumerating everything and testing manually.

BTW: You can make your own iterator which first iterates over the sequence, and then over everything else:

```
function my_iter(t)
    local k, cap
    return function()
        local v
        if k == nil then k, cap = 0 end
        if not cap then
            k = k + 1
            v = t[k]
            if v ~= nil then return k, v end
            cap, k = k
        end
        repeat k, v = next(k)
        until type(k) ~= "number" or 0 < k and k < cap and math.ceil(k) == k
        return k, v
    end
end
```

Though probably better just sort the keys for pretty-printing:

```
function sorted_iter(t)
    local keys, index = {}, 0
    for k in next, t do
        keys[#keys + 1] = k
    end
    table.sort(keys)
    return function()
        index = index + 1
        local k = keys[index]
        return k, t[k]
    end
end
```